# C++ string in a for loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program transcribing DNA to RNA and I cant figure out how to get the program to output a string. I know it involves declaring a string and using it in a for loop. So far, the program that I have outputs the correct answer for only single variables. This is what I have do far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   cout << "> ";
   cin >> dna;
   string dna;
   cout "< ";
        if (a == 'A') cout << 'U';
   else if (a == 'C') cout << 'G';
   else if (a == 'G') cout << 'C';
   else if (a == 'T') cout << 'A';
   cout << " " << endl;
}
```

Comment: where is the character variable a declared? Did you mean to do if(dna == 'A')?

Comment: What's the expected output? p.s. you might want to consider indenting code and using curly braces after if statements {}

Comment: Why not get the code to compile first?

Comment: Please produce an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: i did mean (dna == 'A') and the expected output is when the user inputs a string >ACGT or something along those lines it outputs the the corresponding letters <UGCA and its supposed to work for any length sting input @WadeAnderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this code. Note Your program has several error try to fix them step by step like first of all need to declare a variable before using it or need to write the statement cout<<" < "; insted of cout "<";

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string dna;
   char a;
   cout << "> ";
   cin >> dna;

   cout << "< ";
   for(int i=0 ; i<dna.size() ;i++){

        a = dna[i];
        if (a == 'A') cout << 'U';
        else if (a == 'C') cout << 'G';
        else if (a == 'G') cout << 'C';
        else if (a == 'T') cout << 'A';
   }
   cout << " " << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string dna;
    std::cout << "Type a DNA String\n> ";
    std::cin >> dna;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << "< ";
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < dna.size()`enter code here`; i++) {
      if (dna[i] == 'A') {
        std::cout << "U";
      }
      else if (dna[i] == 'T') {
        std::cout << "A";
      }
      else if (dna[i] == 'C') {
        std::cout << "G";
      }
      else if (dna[i] == 'G') {
        std::cout << "C";
      }
      else return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It asks for an input string, then loops and via conditional determines what to output.

Things to look at:

1. Declare before define
2. Don't compare entire strings
3. Think ahead and setup error-handling.

Comment: I think this is what I need. If you add using namespace std; at the beginning could you avoid having to rewrite it over and over?

Comment: @Tyler It's better to avoid `using namespace std;`, at least in header files. These will expose your code to be prone for namespace clashes.

Comment: Yeah, but if you really want to, then you can remove every single `std::`

Comment: i see. sorry for the double post.

Comment: @Tyler You can delete that comment by pressing the x button. Also, you can accept the one answer you like best or is most useful

Comment: @Isaiah the compiler is giving me an error: there is an invalid use of member (did you forget the '&'?)

Comment: @Tyler Fixed; I don't program a lot in c++ -- add parenthesis after `dna.size`

Answer (score 1):

Your code [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/M6KsQS). You probably meant to write something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()  {
    cout << "> ";
    string dna; // << put the declaration 1st
    cin >> dna;
    cout << "< ";
    for(auto a : dna) {
        switch(a) {
        case 'A': cout << 'U';
           break;
        case 'C': cout << 'G';
           break;
        case 'G': cout << 'C';
           break;
        case 'T': cout << 'A';
           break;
        }
    }           
    cout << " " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Here's the completely fixed and running version.](http://ideone.com/mkBzWx)

Comment: Why would you compare the entire string? You need array access and single quotes were correct to an extent.

Comment: @Isaiah I didn't look about the semantics, the OP was unclear about it. I've just been fixing the obvious stuff.

Comment: Could you do me favor and approve my edit to the question -- it really helps the formatting.

Comment: @Isaiah: I disagree (quite strongly). Rolled it back.